# How do I add additional attributes to an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many

I have an association:

```
class ParentChild < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :parent_id, child_id, position

  belongs_to class2, :foreign_key => "child_id"
end


class Parent< ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many parent_child
  has_many Parent, through: :parent_child
end
```

It works to create a parent and associate another parent:

```
Parent.create.parents << Parent.create
```

but is it possible to set an additional attribute, in this case the position attribute within the ParentChild Model?

Something like this:

```
parent.parents << Parent.create, 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it work as you wrote, you need to use a relationship extension:

```
has_many :parents, :through => :parent_child do
  def << (parent_object, position)
    proxy_association.owner.parent_child.create(:child_id => parent_object.id, :position => position)
  end

  alias :add, :<<
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the `ParentChild` record directly:

```
grand_parent = Parent.create

relationship = ParentChild.create(
                 parent_id: grand_parent.id, 
                 child_id:  parent.id, 
                 position:  3
               )
```